# Jquery - Is it possible to filter elements by class name, and get the index of their parent?

Tags: jquery

In my HTML page, I have nearly 4 `<ul>`s. All have `<li>` children. When the user clicks on each of the `<li>` elements, I am adding the **active** class name. Later, equivalent to the index number of its parent, I'm adding an icon in the icons box (separate boxes).

So, on each click I need to update the index number as well. Is there any way to achieve this?

I used this, but I'm not getting the right results:

```
var lstNum = $('.active').parent().index($(this));
```

I am not getting the value from each parent.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haHYu/)

Comment: Its difficult to understand whats needed here. Can you add a fiddle with what you got so far?

Comment: @3gwebtrain fiddle not having script?

Comment: simply, how can i get the index number of each li has the class name of 'active', for it's parent?

Comment: check my answer. is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Updated **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/haHYu/2/

---

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/haHYu/1/

**Code**:

```
$('.options li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().index());
});
```

Comment: yes, you are correct. but is it possible to get without click the element... like calling a function?